# PROFTPD - Why permission denied?

Tags: linux, proftpd

I installed `proftpd` on my server, I tried to connect to the server but I get `LOGIN INCORRECT`. I have seen the log and I found this:

```
Apr 26 13:02:39 vmi** proftpd[16738] vmi**.**.com (***[::ffff:...*]): notice: unable to use '~/' [resolved to '/home/lighttpd/vhosts/mywebsite.com/web/']: Permission denied
```

The permissions of `/home/lighttpd/vhosts/mywebsite/web` are:

```
drwxr-x--- 2 mywebsite.com mywebsite.com 4096 2011-04-26 12:04 web
```

`proftpd` runs with `proftpd:proftpd` permissions.

To solve this I added the `proftpd` user to the `mywebsite.com` group.

Take a look at `/etc/group`

```
mywebsite.com:x:1003:proftpd
```

So I added proftpd to the group and set RW permissions to `/web` directory.

I don't understand why I get **PERMISSION DENIED**.

Answer (score 1):

Did you restarted proftpd daemon after adding user `proftpd` to `mywebsite.com` group? If you did not then currently running proftpd process doesn't have that group in it's privileges.

If you however did restart proftpd, then try `su` to `proftpd` user and manually enter directory you get permission denied. Maybe you do not have privileges on some higher level directory(ies)...

Comment: `namei -l /home/lighttpd/vhosts/mywebsite/web` is a quick way to see if all parent directories have the required permissions set.